# Eclipseがダウンロードできません。

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipseがダウンロードできません。

JDKのバージョンが1.6.0_65だったので8にアップデートしてからインストーラでダウンロードを開始したんですが、途中でこのようなエラーが出てきてしまいダウンロードできません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
ログはこんな感じです。

```
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_112-b16
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.jee.neon
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.5.0.v20160818-1158, build=2601, branch=bdf2ff7581fb0b3481aab45845b009448eb9c2e6
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.5.0.v20160913-0854, build=2601, branch=bdf2ff7581fb0b3481aab45845b009448eb9c2e6
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.5.0.v20160707-0243, build=2601, branch=bdf2ff7581fb0b3481aab45845b009448eb9c2e6
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Neon))
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Offline = false
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Mirrors = true
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Resolving 63 requirements from 3 repositories to /Users/eito/eclipse/jee-neon9/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement epp.package.jee [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.cft.server.core.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.cft.server.ui.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.datatools.common.doc.user.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.datatools.doc.user.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.datatools.intro.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.doc.user.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jpt.common.eclipselink.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jpt.common.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.common.fproj.enablement.jdt.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.ext.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.server_ui.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.webpageeditor.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2tools.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.dom.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.pde.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.rse.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.rse.useractions.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.common.fproj.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.chromium.debug.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xsl.feature.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201610111000
[2016-11-24 16:09:47] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2016-11-24 16:09:50] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon.
    org.tukaani.xz.XZFormatException: Input is not in the XZ format
      at org.tukaani.xz.common.DecoderUtil.decodeStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
      at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.initialize(Unknown Source)
      at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.initialize(Unknown Source)
      at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:80)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:386)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:193)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:453)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1613)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:416)
      at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

[2016-11-24 16:09:50]
```

こちらが今の環境です。
My browser / operating system: MacOS Macintosh X 10.12.1, Safari 10.0.1, Flash 23.0 (release 0)

Comment: このサイトでは投稿を編集することでトップページに再び表示されるので、再投稿の前にまずはそれを試してみてください。試してみたことを書き足したり、文章をいじってみたり。それでも回答が得られないなら、再投稿したところで回答が得られる可能性は低いですし・・・。質問の削除はやりすぎると[自動的に質問が禁止される](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)こともあるのでご注意ください。

Comment: エラーの出所を追ったわけではないので憶測ですが、 `Input is not in the XZ format` とあるので、インストーラがダウンロードした .xz ファイルが壊れていたのかもしれません。時間をおいて、あるいは別のネットワーク、あるいは別のマシンで試してみるとどうでしょうか。セキュリティソフトが影響していることもあるようです。